# Installing Ruby on Linux

Tags: ruby, linux, apt-get

I want to install only Ruby, not Ruby on Rails, I check this command:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-full -g
```

But the terminal report me this error:

```
E:Command line option 'g' [from -g] is not known
```

This command will install the latest stable Ruby version and will make it
available globally (through the '-g' parameter) on your system environment...

Why do I get this error?

Comment: It means that `apt-get install` doesn't know/have any `-g` option.

Comment: So, What should I do?

Comment: Just `sudo apt-get install ruby` or better yet, install ruby via https://rvm.io/ rather than apt-get.

Comment: -g isn't an option that I see on [apt-get](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get). I personally prefer rbenv vs rvm. Here's a good guide (just don't install Rails at the end) https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/15.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Update your package manager first:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- This must finish without error or the following step will fail.
  Install `curl`:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install curl
  ```
- You’ll use `curl` for installing RVM.
- Install RVM

  ```
  curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
  ```
- You Already Have RVM Installed
  If you already have RVM installed, update it to the latest version and install Ruby:

  ```
  rvm get stable --autolibs=enable
  ```
- Install Ruby:

  ```
  rvm install ruby
  ```

Answer (score 0):

`-g` is not an option of apt-get. There is nothing like "global" install in apt-get. Everything is installed globally. If you want to install the `ruby-full` package, just do

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-full
```

Another option is to install ruby via [rvm.io](https://rvm.io) or [rbenv](http://rbenv.org/)

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get install ruby-full
```

**apt (Debian or Ubuntu)**

Debian GNU / Linux and Ubuntu use the apt package manager. You can use it as follows:

font: https://www.ruby-lang.org/pt/documentation/installation/